# Are region specific claims acceptable?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Up until now, most question have seen have been about universally known topic or person. However, I have been searching for a general rule about the universality of a question and did not found any. I know the claim needs to be notable. But the question is, how much specific a question can be on a geographical region perspective?

For example, I could verify a claim about the president of the united state, but could I do so about the Prime Minister of a province such as mine (Quebec)? If so, can I go as far as asking question about a small organisation?

What are the general rules for determining if a question is too localized or not?

Answer (score 2):

We accept *country-wide* claims.

That is why we have tags like [united-states](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states), [united-kingdom](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom), [italy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/italy), &c.

There are plenty of example questions (just look for questions with the above tags!).